# How is regularization causing gradient error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, gradient

How is regularization affecting the gradients here? Why are W1 and W2 relative errors huge? (Relative error between numerical gradient and analytical gradient)

```
    Testing initialization 
    Testing test-time forward pass 
    Testing training loss (no regularization)
    Running numeric gradient check with reg =  0.0
    tensor(3.4702, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
    W1 relative error: 2.94e-07
    W2 relative error: 1.65e-09
    b1 relative error: 1.01e-06
    b2 relative error: 4.63e-09
    Running numeric gradient check with reg =  0.7
    tensor(35.8447, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
    W1 relative error: 3.20e-01
    W2 relative error: 4.43e-02
    b1 relative error: 2.28e-06
    b2 relative error: 2.90e-08
```

I have this code snippet. How should I debug the error in this case?
code for loss and gradient-

```
loss, dloss = softmax_loss(scores,y)     
loss +=  self.reg * (torch.sum(W1**2) + torch.sum(W2**2))

dx3, dW2, db2 = Linear.backward(dloss, cache3)
dW2 += self.reg * W2
dx2 = ReLU.backward(dx3,cache2)
dx1, dW1, db1 = Linear.backward(dx2,cache1)
dW1 += self.reg * W1

grads = {'W1': dW1, 'b1': db1,'W2': dW2, 'b2': db2}
```

Comment: Impossible to answer since you did not include reproducible code.